# Why does Puppeteer return CSS files wrapped in HTML?

Tags: puppeteer

Gathering a CSS file with Puppeteer gives the content wrapped in HTML. Why is this? What must be done to get pure CSS instead?

For example:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://dss0.bdstatic.com/5aV1bjqh_Q23odCf/static/newmusic/css/newmusic_min_1b1ebf56.css', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

result = await page.content();
```

my expected result is:

`.s-newmusic{position:fixed;.....`

but the result is:

`<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">.s-newmusic{position:fixed;.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppeteer's [`page.content`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagecontent) method returns the full HTML contents of the page (including the doctype). If you open the css file in chrome and open *DevTools > Elements* tab you will see that even in case of a simple text file (like css) there is HTML content. The actual content is wrapped inside a `<pre>` element the same way as puppeteer returned it to you. It has practical reasons: it makes rendering and visualization of text files unified in browsers.

You can get the text content of the css file's `<body>` with [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) like this:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(body => body.innerText, await page.$('body'));
```

Output:

```
.s-newmusic{position:fixed;_position:absolute;width:0;height:50px;left:50%;z-index:100;font-family:arial,...
```